# java.lang.ClassFormatError: Method "<error>"

Tags: java

I was going through `toString()` concept and i wrote `System.out.println("hi");` before `public static void main(String args[])`

```
public class ToString {

    private String city;
    private int pincode;

    public ToString(String city,int pincode){
    this.city=city;
    this.pincode=pincode;

    }
    System.out.println("hi");

     @Override
    public  String toString(){
    return city+" "+pincode;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){

    ToString s = new ToString("pppp",11038);
        System.out.println(s);

    }
```

And on running the code it gave me following error

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Method "<error>" in class Basics/ToString has illegal signature "(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/System$out$println;"
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:476)
Exception in thread "main" Java Result: 1
```

what is the reason ? why cant we write `System.out.println()` before `public static void main(String args[])`?

Comment: What makes you think you can write code like `System.out.println("hi");` outside of a method?

Comment: @Tom        Trying to learn if can write ouside and if not why--is my question than thinking of "hi"!

Comment: Imagine we could write such code outside of a method ... _when_ should it be executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're getting this is because any executable code must be contained in a method. To fix your error you'd have to put the `System.out.println()` inside the method, but you probably knew that already.

You can't execute code outside of methods, unless you put it in a initializer block. That would look like this:

```
public class ToString {

    private String city;
    private int pincode;

    {
        System.out.println("hi");
    }

    public ToString(String city, int pincode) {
        this.city = city;
        this.pincode = pincode;
    }
    //etc
}
```